# JSON.NET Failing Deserialization of a Seemingly Valid JSON Blob

Tags: c#, .net, json, serialization, json.net

I have a JSON blob that I am getting back from a service, that I subsequently convert to a string.

I can, then, easily view that string in the Visual Studio JSON Visualizer if I set a breakpoint for where the string is stored in a variable:

[image]

It's worth mentioning that the JSON data contains a lot of escaped characters, that are, once again, properly rendered in the JSON Visualizer.

The JSON blob that I am getting is following this pattern:

```
[
   {
     "property" : "Value",
     "property2" : "Value\\ of the string."
   },
   {
     "property" : "ValueX",
     "property2" : "ValueY\\ of the string."
   }
]
```

When I start the deserialization process, with the following code:

```
JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();

settings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Include;
settings.StringEscapeHandling = StringEscapeHandling.Default;

List<Station> deserializedYaps = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Station>>(data, settings);
```

I get the following error:

> Error converting value  to type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Beem.StationModels.Station]'. Path
>   '', line 1, position 29904.

Where 29904 is the last character in the JSON string fetched from the service.

The `Station` class is provisioned with the proper JSON property binding and has a default constructor.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Does the JSON pass [jsonlint](http://jsonlint.com/)?

Comment: I was able to deserialize your JSON successfully.  Are you sure the string really has two backslashes, like so: `"Value\\ of the string."`?  Or does the string only have a single backslash and Visual Studio is "helpfully" escaping it when displayed, like so: `"Value\ of the string."` ?

Comment: could you show the `Station` class?

Comment: The JSON above is a test blob, it's not the actual JSON. The string really has two backslashes and it passes JSONLint.

Answer (score 0):

Newtonsoft Json 4.0.5.0 does it fine, assuming the station class looks like this:

```
    public class Station
    {
        public object Property { get; set; }
        public object Property2 { get; set; }
    }
```

You can test it like so:

```
        sb.AppendLine("[");
        sb.AppendLine("   {");
        sb.AppendLine("     \"property\" : \"Value\",");
        sb.AppendLine("     \"property2\" : \"Value\\\\ of the string.\"");
        sb.AppendLine("   },");
        sb.AppendLine("   {");
        sb.AppendLine("     \"property\" : \"ValueX\",");
        sb.AppendLine("     \"property2\" : \"ValueY\\\\ of the string.\"");
        sb.AppendLine("   }");
        sb.AppendLine("]");

        var json = sb.ToString();

        var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings {NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Include};                        

        var deserializedYaps = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Station>>(json, settings);
```

Comment: Like I mentioned, the string above is just a sample. Imagine the same bucket of data, but repeated maybe 60 times. For some reason It just doesn't want to process the data, even as a `JArray`.

Comment: Also, yes, my `Station` class follows the same pattern as you described above.